# How to upload .mp3 files with PHP?

Tags: php, upload, mp3

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="mp3" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I tried the above,and found `var_dump($_FILES);` is always empty.

It only works when you upload text files or images.

**UPDATE**

I added `method="POST"` and it works.Why is `POST` necessary here?

Comment: To answer your update question, you cannot move files through GET so file uploads require you to specify that you are using POST.  MP3 files can get kind of large, so remember to take a look at your php.ini file and possibly adjust the MAX_POST_SIZE and UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE variables so you don't accidentally block out larger files.

Comment: I've also learned that GET can't be used to move files.But what's the reason behind it?

Comment: @user198729 GET is inheriently not secure as it passes data through the URL bar (www.domain.com?name=shane&bank_account=123456&mothers_maiden_name=doe)--on top of that GET can't do anything with binary data (files = binary) but POST, because it works 'behind the scenes' can handle binary data.  I hope that helps!

Comment: There's a limit on how much stuff you can cram into a GET. It varies according to the browser (and the receiving server), but it's a long way from being enough to upload a file this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you specify the form method to be POST explicitly and try?

Comment: +1 I didn't know GET was the default method for forms when none was specified.

Comment: Necessary because of what @Pekka just said. :)

Comment: @Pekka's point is because of size limit of query string.But what if the file itself is very small?

Comment: I just added something on @Pekka's answer that might help!

Comment: I guess maybe the exact reason why GET won't work is in how it's actually implemented.And I decided to take it as granted.

Answer (score 5):

MP3 file uploads should work like any other file upload, there's no discrimination by file type or extension.

Check whether your file is not larger than allowed.

[**PHP manual on file uploads**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

[**PHP manual on file uploads: Common pitfalls**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

**Update:** @Adhip Gupta solved it. GET seems to be the default method for a FORM, not POST as I thought. Check here: [**http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1)

> This attribute specifies which HTTP method will be used to submit the form data set. Possible (case-insensitive) values are "get" (the default) and "post". See the section on form submission for usage information.

Comment: +1 I daresay an MP3 could easily be larger than the distribution php.ini `upload_max_filesize` and/or `post_max_size` vars.

Comment: But the mp3 is not sent at all,I verified this in firebug.

Comment: Huh? That's strange. How large is it? Have you tried setting POST explicitly as Adhip Gupta suggests?

Comment: It's actually caused by `POST`,why is it necessary?

Comment: But why `GET` can't be used to upload files?

Comment: From the document I linked to: `With the HTTP "post" method, the form data set is included in the body of the form and sent to the processing agent.` with GET, all the data is put into the query string. You can't put a file in there, the size limit for the quesry string is 1024 bytes.

Comment: I believe `GET` cannot be used to upload files as then the whole file will have to be passed as a query string parameter (which what `GET` really is). And, query strings have a relatively very small length limit.

Comment: @pekka,so I should be able to submit a file with size 50 bytes via `GET`,right?

Comment: @user189729 I don't know for sure. Try it out!

Comment: I just tried,no.So the reason should not be limit for query string.

Comment: No, the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` only works on a `POST`. I believe that is because the file is serialized before it is sent across the wire. I guess `POST` was made mandatory to avoid issues of sending the converted string via a `GET` because of query string limitations (like `&` will break everything and interpreted in another manner) etc.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is how big the files are, and what the max upload size in PHP.ini is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your PHP code. And neither PHP nor the webserver know the difference between a MP3 file and other types of content.

Have you checked its not size related?

Do you know that there isn't other things between the browser and the PHP which might be filtering?

Have you tried using a wiretap (e.g. wireshark) to confirm the data is leaving the browser / getting to the server?

C.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have missed the MAX_FILE_SIZE which should be included.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="157286400" />
```

You should also add `action="some.php"` and `method="POST"` to `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

OR using http://www.uploadify.com/ with ajax